# Passing a string parametr(s) to javascript function mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am familiarizing myself with mvc and would like to know how to pass a string parameter(query string) to a javascript function using a HyperLink.

```
<td><a href='#' class ="bussinessMetric">@v.Business</a></td>
```

this is the javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".bussinessMetric", function () {

});
```

I want to pass the value of the hyperlink (`@v.Business`) to the javascript function

Comment: No clear. What is the string parameter ? you need it inside click of hyperlink but from where this string parameter will come ?

Comment: Can't you just take `$(this).text()` inside the click function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJSVar= '@v.Business';
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on("click", ".bussinessMetric", function () {
      console.log(myJSVar);
      });
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: @cederlof, still i answered before you :) No prob for your -1 ;)

Comment: I removed the -1 now :) You answered before me, but that was without my answer you later edited in.

Comment: @cederlof, I realized and removed it. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is escaped data, this would work (no need for jQuery).

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction('@v.Business')">click here</a>
```